# how to include php functions from another url (in php)

Tags: php, security, server

I got two websites hosted by OVH

- websiteA
- websiteB

I don't want to have to update same functions on every website.
So I try to figure out the best ( clean / securiest ) way to call functions from websiteA to websiteB

I saw the `"allow_url_include = On"` solution but everybody seems to put huge warnings with that solution.

Is it the only way to proceed ( But I could be attacked if I'm not ultra focus on the security, right ) ?

if no :

- Can I make an equivalent to `"allow_url_include"` but allowed to only connect my trusted server (and reject all other servers ) ?
- Can I somehow connect or merge my servers with OVH ( not the same hosting ) ?
- Should I abord that way of thinking ?

Comment: The best solution for me, is to create a simple deployment script who upload file by FTP directly on two hostings in the same time.

Comment: @user11000657 that make sens.. I'll dig that solution. I script directly with filezilla or I need a new ftp interface ?

Comment: @user11000657 I'm on it.. Thanks for the tip, probably the most secured way =)

Comment: You need to create a script who use FTP protocol, Are you on Windows or Mac/Linux ?

Comment: I am on mac. As you can guess, I'm not an expert in php so the simplest, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for me, is to create a simple deployment script who upload file by FTP directly on two hostings in the same time.